# Слетают стили сайта при добавлении шаблона html.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, themes, php

На сайте используется Drupal 7. Необходимо добавить информацию в head страницы. В теме отсутствует шаблон html.tpl.php. При создании его с содержанием:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <?php print $styles;?>
        <?php print $scripts;?>
        <title><?php print $head_title;?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php print $page_top;?>
        <?php print $page;?>
        <?php print $page_bottom;?>
    </body>
</html>
```

на сайте сползают стили. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Comment: откройте исходный код страницы, посмотрите на ссылку в

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ССЫЛКА">

Всего скорее путь не верный до ссылке генерируется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывать кодировку нет необходимости, вместо этого нужно прописать 
`<?php print $head; ?>`, 
следом сразу тайтл 
`<title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>`, 
после уже подключаем стили и скрипты и к body обязательно добавить вывод классов

```
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
```

Уверен, что тогда все заработает как надо.